# Regex: Match repetitive sequence

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string that defines meta information about a type (i.e. class, member variables) similar to [Serializable] in Unity.

The desired pattern is `* @reflect <Reflect-Data>` where `@reflect <Reflect-Data>` repeats n number of times on the same line.

I can get that to work pretty easily with `^\s+[*](?:\s@reflect\s(.+))$`. The problem is that it does not work with `Serializable, @reflect Range(0, 1)`,

**Scenario 1**

`/**
 * @reflect Serializable
*/
class Test {};`

Captured result: *Serializable*

**Scenario 2**

`/**
 * @reflect Serializable, @reflect Range(0, 1)
*/
private:
float m_foo;`

Capture result: *Serializable, Range(0, 1)*

I think what I am missing it that it needs to capture everything up to the first occurrence of `,` and repeat this n number of times.

I am using python for regex and [this link for testing the regex](https://regex101.com/r/6mWNuF/7/)

Comment: What extra information does ` *` give you at the beginning of the line ? If you can do away with that, it's easy. If you can't you could use the `\G` construct if you use the new _regex_ module. Or, you could keep the ` *` at the beginning, then blindly capture the rest of the line `(?m)^\s+[*](.+)`. On each match, take the contents of group 1 from that match and run a findall on the content using the internal one `@reflect\s+(\S+)`

Comment: @sln `*` gives no extra info. it was just from the style of comment I was using. the `@reflect\s+(\S+)` works like a charm! thank you!